# Remove duplicate MySQL result of query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

I am using SELECT COUNT to check if my mysql table has any duplicates, and when it does, I want it to remove the duplicate.

Here is a screenshot of how the query result looks like:
http://s.prelicio.us/lDyRV.png

Now there are 2 'Aanpassingen voor website Chat-Garden' in my table. That is correct, so I've made it count and where 'Aantal' stands, that's where it'll tell me how many rows have that 'Aanpassingen voor website Chat-Garden'.

But now I want it to remove the duplicate row in my screenshot, since the '2' already has been shown at 'Aantal'. I then do not need the extra row in my screenshot. (excuse me for my bad english)

This is de current code:

```
<?php 

$products = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `preo_invoices-products`');
if(!$products || mysql_num_rows($products) == '0') echo '<li>Er zijn geen producten voor dit factuur.</li>'; 

else $i == '0'; while($product = mysql_fetch_object($products)) {

$color = ($i % 2 == 0) ? ' class="grey"' : ''; $i++;


$result = mysql_query('SELECT *, COUNT(`id`) FROM `preo_invoices-products` WHERE `invoiceid` = "'.$paid->id.'" GROUP BY `description`');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

?>

<li<?php echo $color; ?>>

<span class="inv9"><?php echo $row['COUNT(`id`)']; ?></span> // This one is the 'Aantal' where it shows 2
<span class="inv3">

<?php 
$services = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `preo_services` WHERE `id` = "'.$product->serviceid.'" LIMIT 1');
while($service = mysql_fetch_object($services)) echo strtoupper($service->name); 
?>

</span>
<span class="inv14"><?php echo $product->description; ?></span>
<span class="inv9"><?php echo $product->tax; ?>%</span>
<span class="inv12">&euro;<?php echo $product->sum; ?>,-</span>
<span class="inv15">&euro;<?php echo $product->sum*$row['COUNT(`id`)']; } ?>,-</span>

</li>

<?php } ?>
```

It now actually has to remove the duplicate row, since the 'Aantal' shows me I have a duplicate one. But when I have 3 same rows, it'll show '3' at Aantal, and still has to show 1 row at my screenshot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

you can add `DISTINCT` in your query, example

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tableName
```

Comment: And then use [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) or [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to display a number.

Comment: Do you have an example?
Because the way I just did it, did not seem to work.

I have changed the query to SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `preo_invoices-products`

And added a mysql_num_rows echo where the 'Aantal' is, but now it shows me this:


http://s.prelicio.us/G21ff.png





$result = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `preo_invoices-products` WHERE `invoiceid` = "'.$paid->id.'"');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
           
?>
       
<li<?php echo $color; ?>>
          
<span class="inv9">
<?php echo mysql_num_rows($result); ?> // Aantal

Comment: much better if you will provide sample data in your example so i can show you how `:D`

Comment: This is the table:
http://s.prelicio.us/VgKoF.png

This is the PHP:
http://s.prelicio.us/XaJ2F.png

This is the current output:
http://s.prelicio.us/Qq8fC.png



This is how it should look like:
http://s.prelicio.us/S6bMZ.png (if there are 2 same values at 'description' in the table, now if there are 3, then show '3' at 'Aantal'. Aantal means 'amount'.

Comment: Don't forget to use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` won't do anything.

Comment: I have put the 'group by' back, now it shows me this:

http://s.prelicio.us/HZv0Z.png
While is has to show me just 1 one row now, with '2' in stead of '1' under 'Aantal'

Comment: @ChloëE. do a query that is something like this `SELECT ServiceID, Description, SUM, tax, COUNT(*) Aantal
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ServiceID, Description, SUM, tax`

Comment: @KuyaJohn - Still the same :( -> http://s.prelicio.us/HTkXg.png and http://s.prelicio.us/Hrqy9.png

Comment: can you provide the sample record in text format so we can test it on fiddle? pleaqse don't upload a screenshot

Comment: thanks but that's not what i mean, sample records in your table so we can generate good query

Comment: haha ok sorry im not that good in english, you mean this? http://pastebin.com/CUaq0GQR